# Bootstrap-vue How do I blur the jumbotron background image without blurring the text on top?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to blur the background Image of my jumbotron but the text on top is blurring as well

```
 <b-container fluid class="text-center">
    <div>
      <b-jumbotron class="jumbotron">
        <p style="font-size: 80px; font-weight: 700">
          Welcome to Janes Electrical
        </p>
        <p style="font-size: 40px; font-weight: 700">
          Home Security and Electrical Experts
        </p>
        <p style="font-size: 40px; font-weight: 700">License number: 905</p>
      </b-jumbotron>
    </div>
</b-container>
```

This is my Css

```
.jumbotron {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  filter: blur(5px);
  padding-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("../assets/Test2.jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `::after` for the class `.jumbotron`, make it full width and height and then add to it the effect. If you apply a filter directly to `.jumbotron` it will apply to all its children.

```css
.jumbotron::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  filter: blur(5px);
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/300');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
      Your text
  </div>
</div>
```